# creating low poly rocks using Voronoi texture

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

This video shows a quick way to create rocks using a subdivision and displacement modifier with the voronoi texture.

However @ 17secs I cannot see how it manipulates the rock via the transparent box surrounding it. How is this done?

[image]

https://youtu.be/4EqLyGsu3AA?t=17

Comment: You go into edit mode..? Press tab.

Comment: @Geri: Thanks! That works